# How do we handle questions about unmaintained software?

Tags: discussion, scope

Either on-site or in chat.

I understand that they are technically classifiable as 'software that can be installed', but it gives rise to un-answerable/complaint types of queries.

Simple relatively abstract example:
I want to do this that is available in current mainline someproject
I can't do it in older unmaintained project

If it were actively maintained my answer would be 'file a feature-request/wishlist bug'

If it's not, where do i go from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On-site.
 - If unmaintained, hopefully someone familiar with the project/source passes by...
        - Or someone else takes the time to do so (hint: bounty ;)
 - Not every question has an answer... :p

Comment: Every valid question have an answer even if we are not familiar with it

Comment: @abcd, I meant that "Even if no one has answered an AU question about unmaintained software (yet), doesn't mean it should be closed" sense, not the *"How can I use Ubuntu to prove [P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)?"* sense :P

Comment: @izx While that might not be considered a good AU question, whoever can answer it before it's closed (or migrated) will likely get (1) upvotes, (2) a bounty from somebody, and (3) [$1,000,000 US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems).